# How do copy just text values of cells in Excel

Tags: excel, copy

I have a simple copy button in a worksheet with the code.

```
Range("A9:E19").Select
Selection.Copy
```

I've noticed recently that when pasting the result into an email I get the cells too and not just the text values. I've read a lot of posts relating to pasting values back into excel but as I'm pasting to external email application (ie Gmail) is there a way of controlling what is actually sent to clipboard as opposed to filtering what is pasted which I've seen examples of.

```
    Sub Button1_Click()
Option Explicit
End Sub
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1
''Copy some Range
Range("A9:E19").CurrentRegion.Copy

'Convert it to text and put in clipboard
With dOBJ
    .GetFromClipboard
    S = .GetText
    .Clear
    .SetText S, 1
    .PutInClipboard
End With

End Sub




'Set Reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
Sub CopyText()
    Dim dOBJ As DataObject
    Dim S As String
Set dOBJ = New DataObject

'Copy some Range
'Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Copy


End Sub
```

Comment: Does GMail have an option to Paste Special / Unformatted Text  (as does Outlook)?

Comment: It does have a plain text paste but for some reason it pastes some values that aren't part of the cells text along too. I'm unsure where its getting these from because they don't appear when doing a non paste special. Could it be its translating some formatting to these 'unknown' values. If this is unclear I can post screenshot to better illustrate.

Comment: The screenshot might be helpful

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8EyiQgv6F7mVVIxaktiTDNrY1U&authuser=0[link]

Comment: Those values look like unformatted dates.  Check the contents of those cells by looking in the formula bar.

Comment: In your code above, `Option Explicit` is not at the beginning of the module; the data object and string variable are not declared nor set either globally, or within the procedure where they are being used.  You should read about the proper way to write this kind of code, else you will be running into all kinds of problems in the future.  I'll try to add some code to my response to clarify.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the cells involved as I suggested above?  and also of adjacent cells?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following method, using the DataObject object, might be helpful.  The DataObject is in the Forms Library, and I used early-binding, but you could use late-binding if you are going to distribute this.  It seems to paste plain text using a normal paste in other applications.

```
Option Explicit
'Set Reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
Sub CopyText()
    Dim dOBJ As DataObject
    Dim S As String
Set dOBJ = New DataObject

'Copy some Range
Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Copy

'Convert it to text and put in clipboard
With dOBJ
    .GetFromClipboard
    S = .GetText
    .Clear
    .SetText S, 1
    .PutInClipboard
End With

End Sub
```

Given the code you've posted above, one method of incorporating it into your macro, would be to use the following for the "button" code:=

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'Set Reference to Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library
    Dim dOBJ As DataObject
    Dim S As String

Range("A19:E19").CurrentRegion.Copy

Set dOBJ = New DataObject
With dOBJ
    .GetFromClipboard
    S = .GetText
    .Clear
    .SetText S, 1
    .PutInClipboard
End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT**
Examination of the OP's workbook example reveals that the problem is that there are merged cells, in which the non-visible cells still contain data. The contents is being picked up by the copy operation.

One solution would be to unmerge and remerge the merged cells to get rid of the extraneous data, prior to doing the copy operation.  What affect this would have on the workbook as a whole is unknown.

If the above is a viable solution, then doing a simple copy, and a paste text into gMail, would be an easy solution.  If editing of the merged cells to eliminate the "hidden" data will mess up the workbook, then one could copy to a scratch sheet and make the changes there, before copying to the clipboard.

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense now,I hadn't considered that. Thank you very much :)